# How to properly manage memory in GTK3?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk3

I'm trying to set a small project in C using GTK3.  Coding on linux 64 bits, here is a minimal *Hello world* program I've set up, inspired from the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#gtk-getting-started-hello-world) itself.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void
activate (GtkApplication* app,
          gpointer        user_data)   
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *label;

    window = gtk_application_window_new( app );
    gtk_window_set_title( GTK_WINDOW( window ), "Minimal GTK" );
    gtk_window_set_default_size( GTK_WINDOW( window ), 400, 300 );

    label = gtk_label_new( "Some men just want to watch the world burn." );
    gtk_container_add( GTK_CONTAINER(window), label );

    gtk_widget_show_all( window );
}



int
main(int    argc,
     char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;
    int app_status;

    app = gtk_application_new( "com.github.laerne.minimal_gtk", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE );
    g_signal_connect( app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL );

    app_status = g_application_run( G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv );
    g_object_unref( app );

    return app_status;
}
```

Simple enough.  It works.  However, when running the program with valgrind's memcheck module, valgrind complains about memory leaks :

```
==11415== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11415==    definitely lost: 1,856 bytes in 4 blocks
==11415==    indirectly lost: 7,455 bytes in 320 blocks
==11415==      possibly lost: 4,899 bytes in 56 blocks
==11415==    still reachable: 1,809,562 bytes in 22,030 blocks
==11415==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==11415==                         length64           : 6,240 bytes in 102 blocks
==11415==                         newarray           : 2,144 bytes in 54 blocks
==11415==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11415== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==11415== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==11415== 
==11415== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11415== ERROR SUMMARY: 42 errors from 42 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Running with `--leak-check=full`, I see that GTK allocate a bunch of memory itself, and I'm lost of what needs to be done.  I though that doing `g_object_unref` on the `GtkApplication` was enough to recursively free all widgets of all windows associated with that `GtkApplication`.  Am I wrong ?

What should I do to avoid memory leaks ?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is correct and is almost identical to those in the documentation demos.

GTK and GLib allocate memory for buffers, their own memory management, etc. What Valgrind has reported is unlikely to be memory leaks as this memory is used during the execution of the application, and not freed on application exit but left to the OS to clear up. This appears as a memory leak to Valgrind. A suppression file can be used to help remove the false positives.

Glib and GTK have various options [here](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-running.html) when running your application to help with debugging. You may want to look at the G_SLICE environment variable. You may find [enter link description here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind) useful with information on suppression files near the bottom of the page.